# Oracle Stored Procedure Dynamic Query - How to add an extra column

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am completely new to Oracle stored procedure and now I am trying to modify a sp written by somebody else. It should be very simple but I just don't know how. Here's the sp's skeleton.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE mySP
(
    p1 IN VARCHAR2
  , p2 IN VARCHAR2
  , p3 IN VARCHAR2
  , CUR_S OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
...
...
```

and it goes on build dynamically with bunch of conditions, here's where it builds the query:

```
 my_query := 
  'SELECT '||
     column1_name || 
     column2_name || 
  FROM
     ...
```

all the queries are fine, all I want to do, is to add an extra column in the `select statement` where the value is `p1, the input parameter`

I tried

```
 my_query := 
      'SELECT p1 as newColumnName '||
         column1_name || 
         column2_name || 
      FROM
```

But it does not work. so what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: use `'SELECT ' || p1 || ' as newColumnName ' ||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
my_query := 
      'SELECT ''' ||
         p1 || ''' as newcolumn_name, ' ||
         column1_name || 
         column2_name || 
      FROM
```

Answer (score -1):

Try somthing like this:-

```
'SELECT' || P1 as newColumnName || column1_name || column2_name || 
 FROM...
```

Hope this can help you.